# Not able to create a nullable column of type json

Tags: json, nestjs, typeorm, nullable

I am trying to create a table in postgresql in which one column is of type json, but I want it to be nullable. It seems that nullable option doesn’t work for json type. It is working for jsonb and simple-json, but not for json.

I would like to know if it is a bug, if it is not possible to make a json column be nullable or if I am doing something wrong.

```
  @Column('json', { nullable: true }) 
  myJsonColumn?: MyJsonColumn;
```

Comment: Please share the different `CREATE TABLE` statements that TypeORM generates for each set of column options you've tried.

Comment: BTW, methinks your column property should be `myJsonColumn: MyJsonColumn | null;` not  `myJsonColumn?: MyJsonColumn;` - the column is `NULL`-able, after-all, not `undefined`-able... - I wonder if that's the reason why TypeORM refused to make it nullable?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that typeORM also infer the type of the column from typescript types. So the solution was to use an union type to say it can be null.

```
@Column('json', { nullable: true }) 
myJsonColumn?: MyJsonColumn | null;
```

You can read more about this here:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/759#issuecomment-852238833